# Class not loading on Hosting but works on localhost - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 project running perfectly on localhost. I uploaded the project to a webhost and suddenly i get an error on a simple class.

This is the error:

```
FatalThrowableError in HomeController.php line 20:
Fatal error: Class 'App\Blogpost' not found
```

The Homecontroller code is this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Blogpost;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $blogposts = Blogpost::latest()->take(6)->get();

        return view('pages/start', compact('blogposts'));
    }
}
```

This code is pretty basic and works fine on localhost so i assume that the problem is located elsewhere, but i'm not sure where to begin searching?

For testing purposes i put all the code from Homecontroller in comments and than i just get an error on something else so the problem is situated elsewhere.

My localhost runs on MAMP with a Apache Server with PHP 7.0.0 .
Hosting  runs on Linux + Apache + PHP 7.0.5 .

I have uploaded other laravel projects to the same server with the same configuration without any problems.

this is the link if that helps: [http://dev.mayan-co.com][1]

Extra code to show the Blogpost class itself (still pretty sure the problem is not in that class)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTrait;

class BlogPost extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{
    protected $table = "blogposts";
    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => 'title',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
    ];


    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'featured_image',
        'video_key',
        'body',
        'summary'
    ];

    public function tags()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', "blog_tag", "blogpost_id")->withTimestamps();
    }


    public function delete()
    {
      \File::delete([
        $this->featured_image,
      ]);

      parent::delete();
    }
}
```

Proof that Blogpost.php exists in the correct directory. 
[image]

Comment: Depending on your local machine and the machine you're hosting your app on, there might be an issue with upper/lower case characters in file names (for instance `APp` instead of `App` - have you checked if those are fine?

Comment: i checked for that, the autoloader from laravel seems to handle that and i didn't change any in the filenames manually. I did notice that the server is running on php 7.0.5 & not on 7.0.0 could that be an issue?

Comment: I know you've already answered, but are you 100% sure your not declaring the class as `class BlogPost` or some variation, or that the filename is different in someway? Have you checked the file exists?

Comment: @Jeemusu yes i did check it, i will paste it in my original post. And if that was the case, i probably would receive the same error on localhost.

Comment: try to write **\Blogpost** instead of **Blogpost**

Comment: @Christophvh Your controller is named **BlogPost**.php !! Notice the capital **P**. The file name must reflect the class name, including the case. OSX is not case sensitive in the same way as linux, hence why this doesn't occur on your local version.

Comment: @Jeemusu , that is indeed the problem. I was checking all the 'App' names for capital letters but it was the capital 'P' . Sorry for not noticing it, and thanks very much for your help, you can post the solution as an answer and i will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filename is `BlogPost.php`, yet your class is declared and instantiated as `Blogpost`. The filename and classname need to be identical in both name and case.

OSX is not case sensitive like most versions of linux hence why this is not happening to you on your local version.